# Help Specify possible definitions for this Boolean Function

Tags: probability, algorithms, automata

My math is rusty, but I need some guidance here.

**Problem**

I wish to design a stochastic, boolean procedure $f(state)$, that picks a winner, $f(state_{win})\to 1$ or loser, $f(state_{loss})\to 0$.

I have the following constraints specifying the possible states configurations:

1. The promotion runs from Date $d_1$ to $d_n$ for $N$ days
2. Between the days $d_1$ to $d_n$, there can only be a maximum of $M$ winners.
3. It is preferable (but not necessary) to uniformly distribute the winners over the days $d_1$ to $d_n$, thus, on a given day $d_i$, it is preferable to limit the maximum number of winners to $K = {M\over n}$.
4. On a given day $d_i$, it is also preferable to uniformly distribute the winners across the total number of time units $T$ in the day, so that the probability that a person arriving at the promotion at time $t_j$ can win is $1\over T$.

Additionally, at any given time $(d_i,t_j)$

- let $m$ be the total number of **actual** winners between the day range $d_1$ to $d_i$ **so far**.
- and let $k$ be the total number **actual** winners between the time unit range $t_1$ to $t_j$ **so far**.

It is required to fully define a function or algorithm, $f(i,j,m,k,N,T,M,K)\to [0,1]$

**My Attempt So Far**

$f(i,j,m,k,N,T,M,K) =\begin{cases} 
1 ,\text{if }|rand() - ({N-i\over N}).({T-j\over T}).({M-m\over M}).({K-k\over K})| \le \epsilon \\
0 ,\text{otherwise}  \end{cases} $

Where, $rand()$ is a random-number generating function over $[0,1)$, e.g the inbuilt *random* function of the python programming language.

Am not sure (and that's part of why I need help), whether this implementation of mine is correct (or true to the spec).

**Update**:

Definitely, $rand()$ doesn't necessarily have to be equal to the expression (refer to my attempt), but for $|rand() - expression| \le \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is suitably small.

Comment: First of all, in your attempt, do you mean $f=1$ when $rand() \le ...$? since it's very unlikely that $rand()$ will be equal to a preset value, but you can use a range to determine the output.

Comment: You probably want the probability of winning at a given time to be $K/T$, not $1/T$, otherwise the expected number of winners would be $1$ per day.

Comment: @ShushanWen, yep, actually, the real algorithm am testing is using a range test too - I've updated the question with this info. Thanks.

Comment: @nemesisfixx  Your update doesn't fix the issue.  Since `rand()` has equal probability of outputting any value in the range, the probability of being with $\epsilon$ of some fixed value is always $\epsilon$, regardless of the value.  The expression you should use is $rand() < p$, where $p$ is the desired probability of winning given the state.

Comment: @augurar, not sure I get you right. The recommendation for the $1\over T$ is to ensure that if for example out time units are hours, and the promotion is only active for 6 hours ($T=6$), we want any of those hours (e.g from 06:00 to 11:00) be equally likely to be chosen for a winner. But the $K$, is meant to ensure that for example, a limit to the winners e.g if $K=2$ ensures that only a maximum of 2 customers can win during $T$ - thus, in my attempt I have the expression $({{K - k}\over K})$.

Comment: @nemesisfixx If every hour there is a $1/6$ chance of a winner, then over $6$ hours you expect $1$ winner.  If you want to have e.g. $2$ winners every $6$ hours, there must be a $2/6$ chance of winning each hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial solution.  Suppose you are just trying to distribute $K$ tickets over $T$ time units, $K\leq T$.  What you really want is a *probability* function that assigns a probability of winning, given the state.

Assume that there is exactly one visitor every time interval. Let $t$ be the number of time intervals elapsed and $k$ be the number of winners so far.  I propose the function $p(t, k, T, K) = (K-k)/(T-t)$.

One can easily confirm that this function will always produce exactly $K$ winners, assuming a constant stream of visitors.  I further claim that this probability function produces a uniform probability of $K/T$ of winning at any given time.  The proof goes something like this.  Let $q(t, T, K)$ be the probability of winning at time $t$ given initial conditions $T$ and $K$.  Then $$q(t, T, K) = \frac{K}{T}\cdot q(t-1, T-1, K-1) + \frac{T-K}{T}\cdot q(t-1, T-1, K)\mbox{.}$$  You can use this to inductively prove the claim that $q(t, T, K) = \frac{K}{T}$.

Comment: so, in this line of thought, I could update my expression to $|rand() - ({N-i\over M-m}).({K-k\over T-j})|$,right?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you must use a comparison of the form $rand() < p$.   **The epsilon comparison will not work.**  (This is essential, please ask if you do not understand.)  Once you have done that, you can use the expression $rand() < \frac{K-k}{T-j}$ alone, assuming $K=M/N$, to ensure exactly $K$ winners per day with a uniform distribution on each day, under the assumption of exactly 1 visitor per time unit.

Comment: Thanks, I'd overlooked the fact that K already contains information about M and N. I'll proceed to deploy this solution and assess the practical impact. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you are going to use this in real life, I'd suggest using $V$ and $v$ in place of $T$ and $t$, where $V$ is the expected number of visitors on a given day, and $v$ is the number of visitors so far.